# Dynamic marking "f-p"

Tags: notation, dynamics, repeats

I know that:

- The dynamic marking ***f*** means *forte*, or play loud.  And that ***p*** means *piano*, or play soft.
- The dynamic marking ***fp*** means *fortepiano*, or play this note loud, and play the following notes soft.

---

I have an old music book that uses the dynamic marking of ***f-p*** which I hadn't seen before:

[image: La Bergamesca, with dynamic marking f-p]

I'm not sure how to interpret this ***f-p*** dynamic marking:

- It could be just a different way of writing ***fp***.
- It could mean play some where in the range of ***f*** to ***p***.
- (As it only appears in the book at the start of a repeated section) it could mean play ***f*** on the first play through,  and ***p*** on the repeat.

---

How should I interpret ***f-p****?*

Comment: I think we can eliminate my second guess, because the ***f-p*** on the second line would be redundant.

Comment: I guess a pianist would have to do an *fp* the way you described -- but for almost everyone else, it means that you start the note out loud and then let up immediately.  It's sort of a super-accent.

Comment: @aparente001 - not the easiest to do on piano, and would it only be on the first chord? But it's not that anyway!

Comment: @Tim - As I said, I guess on piano one would have to do what OP described.  I just wanted to make sure OP is aware that that approach is a workaround for instruments that have no dynamic adjustments after striking the note (I'm thinking of percussion too).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It means play forte the first time through, and piano on the repeat.

Answer (score 12):

It gets played as a sort of echo effect. 'f-p' is written to tell the player that it's forte for the first time through, and the repeat is piano. So your third idea is just right. It couldn't be written in a meaningful manner without directly being related to a repeated section.

Answer (score 5):

"forte-piano" is written as: **fp** ... without this: **-** (thread)

**f-p** means: 1. time = **forte,** repetition = **piano**

**Edit:**

> (As it only appears in the book at the start of a repeated section) it could mean play f on the first play through, and p on the repeat.

Like you’re saying ...this reading is correct!
But your other suggestions are wrong.